# .htaccess redirect main domain and not subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have domains mydomain.co and mydomain.com
In mydomain.co I want to install YOURLS.

It is working very well, but I want to create such redirect.

example.org -> R301 -> example.com

example.org/* -> /yourls-loader.php

I have something like this, but it is not working :(

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                                                                                                                           
RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                                                                                                   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.org                                                                                                                                                                          
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com [L,R=301]                                                                                                                                                                     
#RewriteBase /                                                                                                                                                                                                     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                                                                                                                                                                                
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                                                                                                                                                                
RewriteRule ^.*$ /yourls-loader.php [L]                                                                                                                                                                            
</IfModule>
```

How should .htaccess file look for my configuration?

Comment: Could you please accept your answer? This way, your question does not appear as _unanswered_ anymore. Thanks!

Comment: yes, I thought I shouldn't accept my own answer, but I wanted to post correct answer for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've got it working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.org [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourls-loader.php [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and everything that has a subdomain gets redirected to the one without. the rest stays the same.